# Multi level login user and admin?

Tags: java, android, authentication

I have a project to make login app in android studio, and have problem.. and i have code, and this code just basic login (not have level, like admin/user).. and i want to make it have multi level login.
every level of user have diferent activity after click login.. (after admin click login button then go to admin activity and user then go to user activity).
do you have solution to help me?
sorry if my english bad, thanks

this is my code:

```
package com.zahran.login;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.zahran.login.Server;
import com.zahran.login.app.AppController;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
Button btn_register, btn_login;
EditText txt_username, txt_password;
Intent intent;

int success;
ConnectivityManager conMgr;

private String url = Server.URL + "login.php";

private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

public final static String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
public final static String TAG_ID = "id";

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
Boolean session = false;
String id, username;
public static final String my_shared_preferences = "my_shared_preferences";
public static final String session_status = "session_status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    {
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    // Cek session login jika TRUE maka langsung buka MainActivity
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
    id = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_ID, null);
    username = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_USERNAME, null);

    if (session) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
            String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

            // mengecek kolom yang kosong
            if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                    checkLogin(username, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"Kolom tidak boleh kosong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                // Check for error node in json
                if (success == 1) {
                    String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                    Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // menyimpan login ke session
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                    editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                    editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    editor.commit();

                    // Memanggil main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                    intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            hideDialog();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: are you returning user type in response with id and username?

Comment: sorry i was edited my code above, check again

Comment: ya u need to maintain key for admin and user in database. based on that key u change the activity...

Comment: show the log value of `Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());`

Comment: can you post your json respose after successful login @ZahranDiaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve same thing by response only.
Do your code by given example :

```
   [
  {
    "code": 1,
    "msg": "valid user",
    "user_type": "admin",
    "userData": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Abhishek kumar",
        "email": "abhishek@gmail.com",
        "created_at": "2017-09-13 16:54:38",
        "updated_at": "2018-01-25 07:11:56",
        "site_id": 2,
        "dc_id": 2,
        "store_id": 8,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Code will be like this :

```
     if (user_type.equals("admin")){
        // go to Admin Activity
     }else{
      // go to user Activity
     }
```

Final Code will be like this :

```
 // Check for error node in json
            if (success == 1) {
                String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                String user_type= jObj.getString(TAG_USERTYPE);
                String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // menyimpan login ke session
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                editor.commit();

                // Memanggil main activity
                if(user_type.equals("admin")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, AdminActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
               }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

Comment: Happy to help you @ZahranDiaz

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this. for that make your webservice return usertype in response (admin or user). at your side you can do this

```
            try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (success == 1) {
                        String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String User_type = jObj.getString("user_type"); //you need this parameter to dealt with your requirement


             if (user_type.equals("Admin"))
            // go to adminactivity
            else
              go to useractivity.
```